# Find closest date in range with multiple critera

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have 2 tables. What I would like to calculate is the column **Received before CutoffDate*. This column gives me the sum of everything that has been received on dates smaller or equal to the **CutOffDate** for that particular *ItemNo*.

If I isolate my tables to 1 *ItemNo*, I can calculate this but I have not found a way to do this in a general way because my **TABLE 1** has hundreds of *ItemNo*.

**TABLE 1**

| ItemNo | Total Received | PlanRcvDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10560300 | 2 | 3/05/2022 |
| 10560300 | 4 | 28/04/2022 |
| 10560300 | 6 | 27/04/2022 |
| 30238543 | 1 | 1/05/2022 |
| 30238543 | 3 | 29/04/2022 |
| 30238543 | 5 | 28/04/2022 |

**TABLE 2**

| ItemNo | CutOffDate | Received before CutOffDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10560300 | 2/05/2022 | 10 (4 + 6) |
| 30238543 | 29/04/2022 | 8 (3 + 5) |

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Looks like a simple `SUMIFS()` should do. What did you research and attempt? Also, either tag Excel **or** Google-Sheets. They are not the same.

Comment: Also note that Microsoft Excel is not Google Sheets, and there is no guarantee that a solution in one will work in the other. Best to use appropriate tags.

Comment: Search on here, seen similar questions...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B; A:A; E2; C:C; "<="&F2)
```

[image]